# Adding Modules to Python 2.7 Library

Tags: python, module

I've been adding modules to my library so I may call them for future use but when I write a new module and run that module the compiler does not recognize module `unpackapp`. For example, I call:

`from unpackapp import UnpackApp`

Compiler states: "ImportError: No module named unpackapp"

I'm saving to: Python27/Lib

Am I storing my custom modules in the right folder?

Comment: Uh, we don't know. Mostly because we don't know what folder they're in in the first place.

Comment: is `Python27/Lib` in your `$PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 1):

Look into using setup tools and installing using:

```
python setup.py develop
```

If you don't want or need the overhead of setuptools, you can update sys.path to reflect where your module can be imported from:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0. "/path/to/your/module.py's/containing/directory")
```

You can also use "." for a path to refer to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
python setup.py install
```